# C#: Calculate Percentage of new items added over a course of time?

Tags: c#, math, percentage

Say I have a database to which new rows are added everyday. Everyday a percentage of new data added to the database should be calculated against what was there before. That is; show the user a percentage of new data added to the database accumulated within a week.

What I have so far:

- Retrieve table rows and add to a list
- Manage a count of how many rows existed before new addition
- the count is updated and the new count is stored in a separate variable

For example, if I have:

```
int oldCount;
int newCount;
```

How do I calculate the percentage of growth from the oldCount to the newCount so that it displays:

for example:

> 10% growth detected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both counts are non-negative, try to use this:

```
double percent = oldCount == 0 ? 100 : ((double)newCount - oldCount) / oldCount * 100;
```

Comment: The `oldCount == 0` case reports a 100% growth from 0. 100% growth from 0 is 0. I would instead return `NaN` and handle the display message for that case in particular with something along the lines of, "No previous data available.". Since I assume we are setting `oldCount = newCount` and this database only ever grows (per question statement), this case will happen at most once per database.

Comment: My question is: if there was 10 entries before and 2 new entries were added, what's the growth in percentage

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak 20%. And this solution shows it. Set `int oldCount = 10; int newCount = 12;` and verify.